Why the dielectric permitivity matrix of lossless media is symmetric?
I am studying optics and I met a strange statement in the section 2.3.4 (page 34) of Fundamentals of Nonlinear Optics by Peter E. Powers and Joseph W. Haus.
The relationship between $\vec{D},\ \vec{E}$ is (non-principal axis system):
$$
\vec{D}=\varepsilon_0
\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon_{xx}&\varepsilon_{xy}&\varepsilon_{xz}\\
\varepsilon_{yx}&\varepsilon_{yy}&\varepsilon_{yz}\\
\varepsilon_{zx}&\varepsilon_{zy}&\varepsilon_{zz}
\end{pmatrix}
\vec{E}
$$
$$
\overleftrightarrow{\varepsilon}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon_{xx}&\varepsilon_{xy}&\varepsilon_{xz}\\
\varepsilon_{yx}&\varepsilon_{yy}&\varepsilon_{yz}\\
\varepsilon_{zx}&\varepsilon_{zy}&\varepsilon_{zz}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
They say for lossless media $\overleftrightarrow{\varepsilon}$, dielectric permitivity matrix is symmetric and all elements are real. So this matrix is a Hermitian matrix. I can not understand why the matrix is symmetric.
I know this matrix should be Hermitian because it means the existence of real eigenvalues. When we diagonalize the matrix the three principal axes have the real refractive indices.
How do we know the elements of $\varepsilon_{ij}$ should be real for lossless media?

you may find this answer relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/813254/why-are-material-properties-often-described-by-symmetric-tensors/813263#813263

It's hard for me to say because it's something I don't understand, but the next part of equation (13.3) in Landau and Lifshitz' book (Section 13 "Dielectric properties of crystals" in "Electrodynamics of Continuous Media")  explains it.

I mean, both $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ can in principle be measured and are real. Doesn't this imply that the matrix has to be real?

@hyportnex Thank you for your reply.

@HEMMI Thank you for your reply. It helps a little. I will check more details.

@NíckolasAlves Well, you are right. I have thought again and I think the condition of lossless media implies the matrix elements should be real.

As long as the medium is linear and reciprocal, i.e., there are no (magnetic) effect like the Faraday effect, also lossy media have a symmetric permittivity tensor, which has complex elements and is thus not "Hermitian".

Thank you for the reply.

@Hsu Bill That the permittivity  tensor is symmetric has a rather deep going reason. It is related to the Onsager symmetry relations of the dependence of fluxes on thermodynamic forces for small deviations from thermodynamic equilibrium (non-equilibrium thermodynamics) and the time symmetry of microscopic physical processes.

okay thank you for your reply again. I got more details and key words by your reply.
